# UIPickerView Not Reloading with the Latest JSON Data

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Essentially I would like the following UIPickerView to display the latest the options provided by the JSON from the URL - It seems that reinstalling the app grabs the latest data but afterwards its the same. Is there something I am not doing to properly reload the data?

**The following is my code so far:**

```
struct Model : Decodable {
    let model : String
}
```

In `viewDidLoad`

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.test.com/test/test")!
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do { 
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data!)
        self.models = result.map{$0.model}
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    } catch { print(error) }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

**Picker data source methods used:**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return models[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    TextField.text = models[row]
}
```

I thought doing this in Viewdidload would take care of this issue, but if the JSON is updated in the URL, the UIPickerView list still shows the old list of options.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how this view is used. For example, if this view is the main view of your app, `viewDidLoad` will be shown after the view is first constructed and then probably never again.

If this view was a subview that was recreated (a new object was inited), then `viewDidLoad` would be called again.

If you are in the first situation, try `viewWillAppear` to see if that gets you what you want.  That will be called when you return from a subview if it covers the whole view.  If you are doing something more complex, you will have to have other triggers (a timer? -- or perhaps a delegate from the subview) to reload the data.

If that's not the problem -- check to make sure that you code is actually called and that you are getting updated JSON from the URL. If the code is called, and you get the old JSON, it could be getting cached.

Comment: I have already tried adding the code to viewWillAppear with the same result. I know the JSON data is being updated with more data but it is not appearing in the PickerView unless the app is reinstalled. This makes me think it is being cached - is it possible to clear cache?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data!)` and see if you are getting the same data over and over -- if so, type "URLSession cache" in the search bar on stack overflow -- there are lots of questions about it (but be sure that is the issue first)